# Loading config file in Angular, before everything else

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to load config file in Angular application, only the first time when application is opened. Then config variables become globally available across the application. Here is what I come up so far in my *app.js*:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    ...
  ])
  .run(
    [ '$rootScope', '$http',
      function ($rootScope,  $http) {

        $http.get('config/config.json').success(function(data) {
            $rootScope.config = data;
        });


      }
    ]
  )
```

Here I load the *config.js* and when I try to use it in my controller like so:

```
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($rootScope) {
      console.log($rootScope, $rootScope.config);
    })
```

For *$rootScope* I can see all properties including  *config*, but *$rootScope.config* returns *undefined*.

How to load *config* file on first page load and then make it accessible throughout the app?

Thanks!

Comment: It is undefined because you're setting the config asynchronously

Comment: Please check http://www.kidsil.net/2013/07/adding-config-to-your-angularjs-app/

Comment: @Anzeo yes thats true , but how to add a callback, and only then initialize the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Mark Colemans blog post about this](https://markcoleman.silvrback.com/manually-bootstraping-angularjs-after-asynchronous-call), you can get your config and then load the application. Pasting Mark's code for convenience:

```
var urlToCheck = '/echo/json/';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "config", function ($scope, config) {
    $scope.url = config.url;
}]);

$.ajax({
    url: urlToCheck
}).fail(function () {
    myApp.constant('config', {
        url: '/fail-url'
    });
}).done(function () {
    myApp.constant('config', {
        url: '/done-url'
    });
}).always(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: Great, many thanks! I was getting error due to the fact that I still was using ng-app in my index.html. If you could mention that it has to be omitted in your answer for others, it would be great!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it to a promise and then access it in the controller when the promise is resolve. reject the promise too.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EIBJhZg80lpeyhkMD3FD

```
$q.when($rootScope.config).then(function (config) {
  console.log($rootScope.config, config);  
});
```